# Deploy angular dist to server

Tags: angular, deployment

My angular 4 project was compiled successfully.
and "dist" folder is created.

when I move these files to apache server port and RUN from web browser.It is a blank page without any error.

index.html source:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"  class="thin square scrollbar-dusty-grass"  
style="overflow-y: scroll !important;overflow-x: hidden;">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ser Man- Online Service Man Directory</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://127.0.0.1/favico.ico" />
<base href="/">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="runtime-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
<script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
<script src="polyfills-es2015.js"type="module"></script><script src="styles-es2015.js" type="module"> 
</script>
<script src="styles-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="scripts.js" defer></script>
<script src="vendor-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="vendor-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
<script src="main-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="main-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there any console error on your server? Could you please control it?

Comment: no nothing . i heard about shim.js system.js  systemjs.config.server.js and zone.js

how can I use them?